# Print to .pdf and save using specific filename

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

I'd like to print to .pdf out all records of a query, using a report.  I have more than 1k records, and would like to save each record as a .pdf.  I have concatenated the field "filename" within the query, with the intent to save the report using the "filename" field.  The end result would be to click a button "print?" and the database would print to .pdf each record and save the file based on the "filename" field.

I just don't know how to write the vba.

Report: TEMP-Print-CHECKLIST
Query:  TEMP-Print
Save to:  C:\Users\mabanes\Desktop\TC

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "TEMP-Print",CurrentProject.Connection

Do While Not rs.Eof
     'somehow either edit the query here so that the report only takes the record you need for the particular PDF file
     DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "TEMP-Print-CHECKLIST", acFormatPDF, " C:\Users\mabanes\Desktop\TC\" & rs.Fields("filename") & ".pdf", False
     rs.MoveNext    
Loop
```

Comment: Copied/pasted the code.
Received Microsoft Visual Basic dialog box 
- Run-Time error '-2147221164 (80040154)":
- Class not registered
There is a lot of conflicting information about this error...

Comment: What version of Access are you running? On which line of code did you get the error?

Comment: Error on line:
rs.Open "TEMP-Print", CurrentProject.Connection

Access 2007 - 2010